# How can this be minimized?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, optimization

I have the following function of $x_1$ and $x_2$:

$$e(x_1,x_2)= (x_1^2+x_2^2)(a+n)+2a(-x_1+x_1x_2-x_2)+a^2$$
where $a$ and $n$ are real numbers.

I want to find the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ that minimize $e(x_1,x_2)$.

What proceeding should I follow? I'm pretty lost, as there are too many terms involving both $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: well, you can find all the stationary point with the derivatives, and then you can discuss if they are minima or not..

Comment: I was used to solve this by quadratic forms, but this doesn't look like things I was used to deal with. I had never used derivatives for this, how would it be for a 3 dimension problem?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx
is one of the guide that explains how derivatives in more variables are useful to find maximum/minimum/saddle points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$\frac{\partial e}{\partial x_1}=2x_1(a+n)-2a+2ax_2=0 \Rightarrow x_1=\frac{a(1-x_2)}{(a+n)}$$
$$\frac{\partial e}{\partial x_2}=2x_2(a+n)-2a+2ax_1=0\Rightarrow x_2=\frac{a(1-x_1)}{a+n}$$

Can you find the critical points? Note that since $e(x_1,x_2)$ is differentiable, the only critical points are $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{\partial e}{\partial x_1}=0; \frac{\partial e}{\partial x_2}=0$ at $(a,b)$.

Next, we have 
$$D=f_{x_1x_1}(a,b)f_{x_2x_2}(a,b)-\left(f_{x_1x_2}(a,b)\right)^2$$ where $f_{x_1x_1}=\frac{\partial^2 e}{\partial x_1^2}$ and $f_{x_1x_2}(a,b)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}\left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial x_2}\right)$

If $D>0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b)>0$ then $(a,b)$ is a relatively minimum. If $D<0$ we have a saddle point. If $D=0$, then we could have a relatively minimum, a relatively maximum, or a saddle point. You most likely would have global minima for $(a+n)>0$ (Notice how $e(x_1,x_2)$ looks like a parabola).